# Using pyarrow strings with pandas map or apply

Tags: pandas, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I trying to create a new DataFrame column based on a transformation from another.
I'd like to have the return dtype as `pyarrow[string]` and not `object`.

I can do

```
In [2]: s = pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 2])
In [3]: names = {1: 'Creative', 2: 'VeriFone'}
In [4]: s.map(names)
Out[4]: 
0    Creative
1    VeriFone
2    Creative
3    VeriFone
dtype: object
In [5]: s.map(names).astype('string[pyarrow]')
Out[5]: 
0    Creative
1    VeriFone
2    Creative
3    VeriFone
dtype: string
```

But this create an intermediate series with `object` dtype.

I also tried:

```
In [6]: arr = pa.array(['', 'Creative', 'VeriFone'])
In [7]: s.apply(arr.__getitem__)
Out[7]: 
0    Creative
1    VeriFone
2    Creative
3    VeriFone
dtype: object
```

But the return dtype is `object`.

Is there a way to directly create a pd.Series with `string[pyarrow]` type from `s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `pd.Series.map` or `pd.Series.apply` python code gets executed so there will be an intermediate python object no matter what.

If you're looking for performances it's best to use vectorized operations. For example you can use join:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 2])
names = pd.Series({1: 'Creative', 2: 'VeriFone'}, dtype='string[pyarrow]', name='name')
s.to_frame().join(names)['name']
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about join/merge.